# Deploying Rails Application in AWS OpsWorks

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, deployment, chef

I've created a stack, inside this stack have created two layers.

- Rails App Server (Ruby version: 2.0.0, Rails Stack: nginx & Unicorn, **no custom chef recipes**)
- MySQL (using **built-in recipes**)

And have created two instances. 
And finally **App** description like:

Rails Environment: **production**

Document Root: **public**

Repo type: **Git**

And then I've deployed this `App`. It's deployed successfully!

```
I can provide you deploy log but don't know which portion of log should post here?!
```

But in public IP it's redirecting to `500.html` page! Please help me out, have been stuck here two days.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the Rails Environment to `development`, redeploying, and seeing the more verbose output? This might be the first step into finding more details.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try out logging in to that server and then checking out what was the issue, you could do a `tailf /var/log/nginx/error.log` and see what you are getting in your latest line when you refresh the page